# Second moment of a Geometric Brownian Motion with Mean Reversion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following SDE:
\begin{equation}
d x_t = \kappa (\theta - x_t) dt + \sigma  x_t d W_t \  ,
\end{equation}
where $\kappa$, $\theta$, $\sigma > 0$ and $W_t$ is a Brownian motion.

Is it possible to find an analytical expression for $E_s \{ x^2_t \}$? I started looking for a solution similar as for the CIR process, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: :what is $r_t$ here ?

Comment: @Khosrotash It should be $x_t$, I have edited the question.

Comment: @BEQuant:see this post,may helps you     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547273/solution-of-an-sde/4001537#4001537

Comment: $$d(x_t^2)=2x_t\,dx_t+(dx_t)^2=2κ(θx_t−x_t^2)dt+2σx_t^2dWt+σ^2x_t^2\,dt,$$ so that for $u_t=E[x_t]$ and $v_t=E[x_t^2]$ you get the ODE system $$\dot u_t=κ(θ−u_t), \\ \dot v_t=2κ(θu_t−v_t)+σ^2v_t.$$

Comment: Just to correct my previous comment (which I deleted). This SDE has the [solution]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Some_explicitly_solvable_SDEs[4]
$$
x_t=\Phi_t\Big(x_0-\int_0^t\frac{\theta\kappa}{\Phi_s}\,ds\Big)
$$
where
$$
\Phi_t=\exp\Big(\kappa t-\frac{\sigma^2 t}{2}+\sigma W_t \Big)\,.
$$This approach looks ***tricky***. @LutzLehmann : Nice !

Comment: @LutzLehmann It may be a good idea to post that comment as an answer instead so the question may be marked as answered.